# How to extrude along angles

Tags: extrude

I got a 4 sided plane in Blender, if it wasnt obvious, its the one ive highligthed with the red marker. As you can see, the top is flat. What i want is for this plane to be a triange. How can i do this, I tried to loop cut the plane in the middle, but i do not know how to extend the line

If it wasnt clear, the shape i want is the same shape as the red marker.

[image]

Comment: Just select the top vertices, then hit `M` > _Merge_ > _At Center_. Of course the angle of the edges on the side will change then. If you do not want that, which one do you want to preserve? For this, use @penguinologic's answer. Or preserve both angles and extend the face upwards until the vertices meet?

Comment: yeah, i need to preserve the angles of the edges so that it lines up to the two pieces flanking the triangle.  I need to preserve all angles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vertex slide, by selecting one of the vertices and double-tapping G, then sliding the vertex to the opposing vertex.  Next, press A to select all, press M to merge, and merge by distance to remove the duplicated vertices.

Comment: What you mean (double-tap `G`) is _Vertex Slide_, the shortcut for _Loop Cut and Slide_ is `Ctrl`+`R`.

Comment: Thanks for catching that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve **all** angles and only want that one quad to become a triangle, why don't you simply select the left face and move it over by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> with *Snapping* set to *Vertex* until the top left vertex of the soon-to-become-a-triangle quad snaps to the top right one? Then select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge* > *By Distance* to remove the duplicate vertices? Of course the bottom edge of the triangle is then shorter as before, but you cannot have all - preserve all angles **and** all edge lengths.

[image: move and snap]

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the statement in the OP "I tried to loop cut the plane in the middle, but i do not know how to extend the line". It makes me think that the triangular shape is to extend upward in the shape shown with the red marker.

I used two addons that come with Blender: Add Mesh: Extra Objects for the single vert and Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools for the extend line.

I put the cursor on the vertex where the gizmo is. In Object mode I added a single vert and extruded it to get this shape:

[image]

Then select an edge and right click to get this menu:

[image]

I got this by clicking on extend:

[image]

Do the same for the other edge:

[image]

With Edge Snapping and Auto Merge Vertices turned on, extrude a vertex to the intersection of the lines:

[image]

With Vertex Snapping on, extrude that vertex to the vertex in the extended line:

[image]

Select and delete the extended edges:

[image]

Select and dissolve the vertices in the edges:

[image]

Select the edges and press F to fill and check face orientation:

[image]

In my case it needs correcting. After this, you will have a separate object. If you want to you can join it to your other object. After joining do a merge by distance.

Comment: Yeah, actually when I asked in the comments if it should be extended upwards and if angles should be preserved I thought on keeping the corner vertices connected to the surrounding faces... the response I got was about the angles but ignoring the "extend upwards" part. That's why I dismissed this solution you show here. But I guess this is probably just ecactly what the OP wanted.